# Replace varying string with regex nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I need to identify patterns similar to the following inside of a very large string and replace them with "null":

`["pmeta", ["ImageSelectStoreFront", null, 3, 4, 2, null, "Storefront", []]],
["pmeta", ["/m/01pns0", null, 3, 3, 3, null, "fire hydrant", []], null, [1]],
["pmeta", ["/m/0199g", null, 3, 3, 3, null, "bicycle", []], null, [1]],`

These strings appear to be JSON, but the string that they appear is is not JSON, so no sense in parsing it. I also do not need to parse this JSON, I need to remove it from the string that it appears in.

The only parts that are always the same are 
`["pmeta",`
and the closing bracket and a comma at the end.

I am exploring regex as a possible solution, but I am completely new to it and have not come up with anything close to useful.

Can anyone give me some regex pointers or suggest other ways to accomplish this?

Comment: Parse the JSON instead

Comment: It's not clear what you want to replace

Comment: @CertainPerformance This actually would not be useful to me. This JSON shows up in a string and I need to get rid of it not parse it.

Comment: @adiga I need to replace any string that starts with `["pmeta",` and ends with the final, closing bracket, and everything in between.

Comment: An example of a string containing the expression that I need to replace can be found here: https://pastebin.com/c9h3jYWh
Line 6 is where the code that I need to replace starts.

Comment: Parse JSON -> filter -> serialise to JSON, that should be a lot easier. A regex is going to be very annoying to write and maintain. A custom parser would be *easier* by comparison but still a lot more work than a trivial parse -> filter -> serialise.

Comment: @VLAZ Although the code that I need to replace is JSON, the string that it occurs in is not so I could not parse it, right?

Comment: So, it doesn't show up inside JSON? Are you not parsing it eventually?

Comment: @VLAZ No it doesn't, look at the pastebin link. I am never going to parse anything, I just need to remove these JSON bits from the string. Since these strings that need to be removed always start with `["pmeta",` and and with a close bracket and a comma, it shouldn't be too hard to figure out with regex I would assume.

Comment: @Joxrox ok, I see the problem, then. So, let me clarify - you want to remove from `["pmeta"` to the end of that "array", correct? Can you have more than one occurrence in a string?

Comment: @VLAZ Exactly, and only one occurrence per string. Daedalus, I am not sure what else I can say to make it more clear but I will try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a regular expression, you could do custom parsing. It works in the following way:

1. Find if there is anything that starts with `["pmeta"` in the input.
2. Count that as the `startIndex`
3. Find the index of the last closing bracket after that index by keeping a stack of brackets. You add one element to the stack for every open bracket, remove an item for any closing bracket. When you empty the stack, that's the last closing bracket. Count that as `endIndex`
4. Find the section of the string from `startIndex` to `endIndex` and then replace it with `null`.

I have shortened (and anonymised) your sample by replacing the long values to single words:

```js
let input = `)]}'
["rresp",
"one",
null,
120,
["pmeta",["/m/01pns0",null,3,3,3,null,"fire hydrant",[]
]
,null,[1]
]
,"dynamic",null,["bgdata","two","","three"]
,"four","five"]`

let output = clean(input);
console.log("output", output);

function clean(text) {
  let startIndex = text.indexOf('["pmeta"');

  //nothing to remove - early exit
  if (startIndex === -1) return text; 

  let endIndex = findLastOpenBracket(text, startIndex);
  
  let toReplace = text.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
  console.log("found text to replace:", toReplace);
  
  return text.replace(toReplace, "null")
}

function findLastOpenBracket(text, startIndex) {
  let openBrackets = [];
  
  for (let i = startIndex; i < text.length; i++) {
    let char = text[i];
    if (char === "[") {
      openBrackets.push(char);
    } else if (char === "]") {
      openBrackets.pop()
      
      if(openBrackets.length === 0){
        return i + 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This assumes there *would be* a closing bracket that ends the sequence. Admittedly, the `findLastOpenBracket` function can be improved a lot but I don't know the requirements here and it fits the sample data. At the very least, it's a single algorithm that can be replaced, the rest of the steps stay consistent.

Another note: step 4. is a bit cumbersome. Unfortunately, there is no `.splice` method for strings in JavaScript, so you have to go the long route - get the substring -> replace the substring in the string. You can instead use the `Array.splice()` method, if needed but I find it cumbersome, as well:

```js
let text = "one,two,three";

//replace "two"
let startIndex = 4;
let endIndex = 7;


let arr = text.split("");
arr.splice(
  startIndex, 
  endIndex - startIndex, 
  "null"
)

let output = arr.join("");
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, I'll look into this solution tomorrow - getting very late here :)

Comment: Some later thoughts - I just realised, keeping a stack for the brackets is an overkill here. You could do it with a single counter `openBrackets = 0` and increment it for each open bracket, decrement it for each closed one. I guess that's better but, as I said, there is a lot that can be improved for that function. It can be generalised to any type of bracket and/or quotes. I'll leave it as is, however.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, there is only one occurrence of the pattern in a string, and that there aren't any other occurrences of `],` then `\["pmeta",.*\],` could work. Regex demo: https://regex101.com/r/4DSfVR/1

JavaScript implementation:

```js
inputstr = 'djfhjkdfhkhdf ["pmeta", ["ImageSelectStoreFront", null, 3, 4, 2, null, "Storefront", []]],jdkfhkjdhf';
pattern = new RegExp('\\["pmeta",.*\\],',"gm");
console.log(inputstr.replace(pattern,""));
```

Comment: This doesn't work with the sample OP posted in the comments

Comment: @Joxrox but it [literally doesn't work the sample you posted](https://jsbin.com/yodivafedi/edit?js,console)

Comment: @VLAZ true. I didn't see the pastebin before posting. Like I mentioned, this regex only works if there are no other occurences of `],`. I also didn't consider that the pattern may contain new lines (the `\s` flag would take care of that).